# Expected maximum of maxima

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $F(x)$ denote some CDF, and $\{f_i\}_{i=0}^m$ be a set of random variables independently drawn from that distribution.

I would like to compute

$$ E\bigg[ \max\bigg\{ \max\bigg\{\{f_i\}_{i=0}^m + k_m\bigg\}, \max\bigg\{\{f_i\}_{i=0}^n + k_n\bigg\}\bigg\}\bigg] \tag 1$$

where $k_m$ and $k_n$ are real constants.

I *can* compute the expected value of the inner maxima separately, i.e. I have a closed-form solution for

$$E\bigg[\max\bigg\{\{f_i\}_{i=0}^m + k_m\bigg\}\bigg] = E[\max\{\{f_i\}_{i=0}^m\}] + k_m \tag 2$$

This has a closed form because $F(x)$ is Frechet, and hence the expected max of a set of RV distributed Frechet is a RV also distributed Frechet.

Is there any way I can rewrite (1) into components of (2)? Does it help that, by independence assumption of the single draws $\{f_i\}$, the two sets $\{f_i\}_{i=0}^m$, $\{f_i\}_{i=0}^n$ are also independently distributed?

If not, is there any upper bound to the difference beween $E[ \max\{max\{f_i\}, max\{f_j\}\}]$ and $\max\{E[max\{f_i\}], E[\max\{f_j\}]\}$